# How does Google or any other social media sites know what password I've used previously?

Tags: passwords

When I ask to change my password, Google sometimes doesn't allow identical passwords to ones that I've used before.  Is there a reason why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what @QuBit5 said, it's pretty common practice to store not only the user's current password's hash/derived key, but also store them for the user's last X passwords (where X varies from 1 to infinity, but is usually less than 10). When the user tries to change their password, or requests a password reset, they aren't allowed to re-use one of their old passwords on the assumption that old (or previously-lost) passwords are more likely to have been compromised by an attacker, and therefore should not be used again. The software (on the server) runs the password through its hash/key derivation function, and checks the resulting value against the values for the user's old passwords. The password change/reset only succeeds if the new password has not been used before.

This type of scheme is most commonly paired with a mandatory password expiration, on the basis that using the same password for too long makes it more likely to have been compromised. Obviously, such a scheme could be bypassed by users changing their password to a temporary one and then changing it back immediately to their long-term one, hence the need to remember the old values. It is also sometimes used after a security compromise that may have resulted in the authentication data being accessed, on the basis that all passwords in use at the time of the compromise should be assumed to be compromised and should never be used again.

Answer (score 3):

These sites store your previous passwords in *some* form. It could either be in plain text (i.e. the password as it is) OR a hash (eg. SHA256 or [better](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function)) of it.

Storing plain text passwords is a bad design security wise because it leaves your password in the database which can be reused as it is if the database is compromised.